# Is S3 multipart upload using pre-signed Url (Query string authentication) possible using AWS java sdk?

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I wanted to know whether it is possible to perform S3 multipart upload using pre-signed Url using AWS java SDKs.
Unfortunately i am not able to get any clear answer for it, not sure whether it is supported or not.
Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a chance to examine the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html)?  You will want to presign a [create multipart upload request](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/blob/94f5744ac5678597f976c2073f58f33ada063e57/services/s3/src/main/java/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/presigner/S3Presigner.java#L355).  A related issue includes this comment https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/203#issuecomment-663631708 which shows code from the relevant integration test.